# Question on passing a pointer to a structure in C to a function?

Tags: c, pointers, linked-list, structure

Below, I wrote a primitive singly linked list in C. Function "addEditNode" MUST receive a pointer by value, which, I am guessing, means we can edit the data of the pointer but can not point it to something else. If I allocate memory using malloc in "addEditNode", when the function returns, can I see the contents of first->next ?  Second question is do I have to free first->next or is it only first that I should free? I am running into segmentation faults on Linux.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct list_node list_node_t;

struct list_node
{ 
  int value;
  list_node_t *next;
};

void addEditNode(list_node_t *node)
{
   node->value = 10;
   node->next =  (list_node_t*) malloc(sizeof(list_node_t));
   node->next->value = 1;
   node->next->next = NULL; 
}

int main()
{
  list_node_t *first = (list_node_t*) malloc(sizeof(list_node_t));

  first->value = 1;
  first->next = NULL;

  addEditNode(first);

  free(first);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Is this homework? It should have the homework tag if so. Beyond that, the code above is fine except for your free. You need to free all memory you've malloc'd. Create a loop that traverses the list, freeing the nodes as you go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, yes you can "see" the contents of `first->next` when the function returns. `node->next` is a value in the struct pointed to by `node`, which points to the same place as `first`. When passing the `first` pointer by value, only the pointer itself is copied, not the whole structure it points to. In other words, `*first` in `main` is exactly the same data as `*node` in `addEditNode` (not a copy), it's just that each function has a *different* pointer (one called `first` and one called `node`) that point to that one structure.

Second, yes you must free `node->next` as well or you will have a leak. When you free a pointer to a structure, it does *not* recursively free pointers that are members of that structure.

However, I don't see anything in that code that is incorrect or that should cause a segmentation fault (a leak won't cause a segfault).

Answer (score 2):

> .. means we can edit the data of the pointer but can not point it to something else...

**Yes**

> If I allocate memory using malloc in "addEditNode", when the function returns, can I see the contents of first->next ?

**Yes. The memory is allocated on the heap, so you can access it. Note that you are still responsible for freeing the memory.**

> Second question is do I have to free first->next or is it only first that I should free?

**Yes. You are supposed to free all memory allocated on the heap.**

---

Although, there is a memory leak (`first->next` not `free`d), but you probably should not get seg-fault.

*Note:*

```
node->next =  (list_node_t*) malloc(sizeof(list_node_t));
```

Explicit casting is **not required** in case of `malloc` in C (required in C++). The following is just fine.

```
node->next = malloc(sizeof(list_node_t));
```

Answer (score 1):

> If I allocate memory using malloc in "addEditNode", when the function returns, can I see the contents of `first->next` ?

Yes, you can see it in `main`.

> Second question is do I have to free first->next or is it only first that I should free?

You should also free `first->next`, otherwise you get a memory leak.

A segmentation fault you may get if you try to dereference `first` after disposing it.

Note however, that removing a node from the linked list also requires rearranging the pointers to keep the list in a valid state. You should write a separate function for this.

Answer (score 0):

A pointer is an integer which designates an address in memory. The details of 'memory' are left unstated here; just know that a pointer contains a number which is an absolute byte in your program's address space.

When you pass a pointer therefore, you pass an address. So by editing the data at the address, you cause your changes to be made visible outside of the local function. So yes, you will see the changes made within addEditNode() in main().

When you dynamically allocate memory, you should always free it. Changes made to the heap are global to the program.